# How to search for a subject like this

Tags: git, git-config

To do a git commit with my own editor (Visual Code)

I needed to setup the editor like this:

```
git config --global --replace-all core.editor "code -w"
```

I was searching for this a long time and found out the `-w` was missing after code.

Without StackOverflow I would probably never know this. Can you explain me a little bit how I can solve such problem. In `git config --help` or the documentation of git I coulnd't find anything about the `-w` at the end.

Where did people on StackOverflow found about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that this `-w` param is not one from Git but from VS Code.
You can find documentation about it there: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/command-line

How you could have understood that? If you look at the command, the `-w` is inside the `""` block so it means it is part of the command you pass to the Git config, so a parameter of the VS Code command line tool.

Answer (score 1):

The `-w` is a parameter to VS Code, so you'll not find it in git's help.
You could have found it using `code --help` or [online here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/command-line#_core-cli-options)